# C++11 compiling with clang++

Tags: c++, c++11, clang++

I'd like to run my code on large datasets. Hopefully I have access to large servers with >10 core and 64G of ram ...

My issue is that thoses servers only have `gcc 4.6.3`.
As my code is `c++11`, I need another compiler ... and hopefully `clang 3.0` is availlable.

On my laptop I compile my code with

```
g++ -pipe -march=native -std=c++11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3
```

however, if I try to compile using `clang++` with

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -O3
```

I get strange errors :

```
/usr/include/c++/4.6/chrono:666:7: error: static_assert expression is not an integral constant expression
      static_assert(system_clock::duration::min()

include/hierarchie/octree.hh:64:146: error: use of undeclared identifier 'pt'
  ...end,          [mid](const geometry::physpoint3D& pt){ return pt.z() < mid.z(); } );
```

What's wrong ? Is there any modification I should make to my code to "adapt" it to clang ?

Comment: what version of clang are you using? it seems it doesn't support C++11. For example, lambda expressions are not supported in clang 3.0, see http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html

Comment: Your clang appears to be using libstdc++ headers. As your gcc is outdated, so are its libstdc++ headers. It would not surprise me if there are issues in those headers that have since been fixed.

Comment: It's clang3.0-6 (ubuntu machine to which I dont have root access)

Comment: Just compile the application somewhere else with -static-libstdc++, no need to compile it on the target computer.

Comment: The code uses openmp. Won't that be an issue if path to lib differ ?